# How do you reposition a UIMenuController in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uimenucontroller

I've added a custom item to a UIMenuController for each UICollectionViewCell and it shows up just fine and the action is firing. However, I would like it to be positioned, not in the middle of the cell, but in the center of the label (see screenshot). I've tried setting the `targetRect` but the position seems to be static. Is there a straightforward way to update it's position?

[image]

Comment: What if you manually show the menu? Then you have full control. The automated behavior will center it... but manually showing isn't much more work.

Comment: Thank you for tip @steipete. I'll go down that path now